# Simple Drag and Drop JS Script not Working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry, english not best!

I tried using this simple Javascript and HTML, and CSS, drag drop, and get no correction!

Take look at website, everything is fine, yet not working?

http://bouncygames.org/smell.php

Answer (score 1):

You gotta install jQuery and jQuery UI first mang `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

http://jqueryui.com/download/

Comment: How can I install jQuery on my site?

Comment: Thanks, how can I install it on x10hosting

Answer (score 1):

You don't have jQuery and jQuery UI installed.

To do this add the following lines to your head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please select answer if you found it useful!  Thanks

Comment: Can you help with one more thing

Comment: Refresh one more time and look at http://bouncygames.org/smell.php, how come this handle isnt working

Comment: Like a window style:  I wish for like this:  http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex11/domdrag/example.htm